# How do I force Adobe Camera Raw to use monitor color profile?

Tags: photoshop, raw, color-management, adobe-camera-raw

How do I force Adobe Camera Raw to use monitor color profile ?

I shoot in RAW. sRGB is set on camera.

The problem is that **after** I open my photo in Photoshop and enable "Proof Colors" (set to "Monitor RGB") it looks pretty different that it was in Adobe Camera Raw (ACR).

That means I can't do color correction in ACR.

What should I do ?

Comment: See also: [What are Color Profiles and where would I find information on using them properly?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2624/what-are-color-profiles-and-where-would-i-find-information-on-using-them-properl/2626#2626)

Comment: See also: [How much of a difference do different color spaces make?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-much-of-a-difference-do-different-color-spaces-make/6435#6435)

Comment: See also: [Which color settings to chose in Photoshop and Aperture with an Epson SPR2880 printer](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19778/which-color-settings-to-chose-in-photoshop-and-aperture-with-an-epson-spr2880-pr/19786#19786)

Comment: See also: [What steps to take to match screen to print?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/what-steps-to-take-to-match-screen-to-print/20771#20771)

Comment: I realize I have the same problem, after trying to calibrate my images using a colorchecker. I spent a LOT of time and the colors were never right, despite being calibrated. Then using the proof setup and my monitor profile in Photoshop everything was marvelous, with the same files. The colors in ACR always look bad and cannot be used at all. But the files (arw, dng) are actually ok if I use something like Picasa (dng, arw), Windows 7 Explorer Preview (dng), or Photoshop (dng, arw) with proof colors. I didn't find any way to display correct colors in ACR.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's relevant to the core issue, but setting the colour space on the camera does not have any effect on the raw files, only on jpegs – such as the one that's embedded in the raw file that the camera uses for its preview and histogram.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Monitor RGB profile to display an image on a monitor calibrated to use the same profile is equivalent to turning off calibration, are you sure this is what you want?

You can turn off Proof Colors in the View menu while editing . It's not necessary to keep turned on unless you are proofing an image for a specific viewing environment/print setup, which can be done after all major editing has been finished.

In order for your image to look the same in Camera Raw and Photoshop you need to make sure that they are set to use the same color space. In Camera Raw you set the color space by clicking on the underlined information at the bottom of the interface. In Photoshop you use the Edit > Color settings screen.

**UPDATE**: The 'Proof Color' option in Photoshop is intended for simulating the appearance of an image on a specific output device, which should be done after general editing is complete. The result of general editing should be an image that looks correct in the working space, which will reduce the level of tweaking required to get the best possible output for any specific device. You can see [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2624/9646) question for more details on color management and [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/17799/9646) question for how to make it easy to get back into camera raw after opening an image.

Comment: I can't select custom ICM for my monitor in combo-box of ACR. There are only 4 profiles: sRGB, ProPhoto RGB, ColorMatch RGB and Adobe RGB.

Comment: Using the Monitor RGB profile when editing an image is not a good practice, why are you using it?. If you want to have your image look as good as possible on as many different monitors as possible then edit the RAW file using a wide-gamut space (Adobe RGB or ProPhoto RGB) and then create a JPEG using sRGB when you are finished editing.

Comment: Makes sense. I don't mind using any color space. But how can I proof color in ACR ? My problem is that I cannot do color correction in ACR because it will look different in Photoshop after I open the file (with enabled Proof Color).

Comment: @ruslan: You don't quite seem to fully grasp image color management. Each component of a color managed process must have its own profile. Your image has a profile (i.e. sRGB, AdobeRGB, ProPhoto RGB), your monitor has a profile (calibrated by a device), your printer has a profile (calibrated by another device), etc. The ICM engine is responsible for producing accurate color on any given output device by using the profiles of each to convert from one color space to another.

Comment: You should be using sRGB or AdobeRGB for your image...don't use the monitor profile for the image...otherwise your telling the ICM engine that the image is already using the same color data as the monitor, and it will not convert from the image color space to the monitor color space properly. If you need to "proof" the image for print, ACR is not the place to do that. Photoshop has a print soft proofing mode that will assist in that endeavor AFTER you finish your ACR work.

Comment: There is an additional component that is kind of side-band to ICM when it comes to photography. Calibration of the camera itself. The image produced *by* the camera will usually have a profile, either sRGB or AdobeRGB. However each camera has its own physical hardware nuances. ACR DOES allow you to configure this with camera profiles. When you work an image with ACR or LR, you can change the camera profile to tune how the image looks. These usually match the camera's built-in picture styles...like Portrait, Landscape, Standard, etc.

Comment: (sigh..) I understand that. I don't print my photos. I just want to make sure that when I'm editing photo it will look the same everywhere. That's why I calibrated my monitor (and camera). But the problem is that ACR doesn't respect custom ICM of my monitor therefore visual representation of my photo in ACR has wrong colors. Do I understand it correctly? If yes what is the workaround for this issue?

Comment: @ruslan: The profile used in ACR and the profile for your monitor are used for different purposes. The ACR profile is used to interpret the values in the RAW image in order to generate a usable image while the monitor profile is used to get the usable image to be displayed as correctly as your monitor is capable of. To get the widest possible compatibility you want your final images to be in the sRGB color space.

Comment: It still doesn't answer my question. Sorry. Could you please take a look at this question? I narrowed it a little.  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25050/does-proof-color-with-monitor-rgb-option-in-ps-ensure-that-i-see-true-colors

Answer (score -1):

> How do I force Adobe Camera Raw to use monitor color profile ?

You probably can't without some serious hacking, but device profiles should not be used for editing anyways. If you insist on converting the image to device profile, use ProPhoto RGB and do Convert to Profile (specifying the device profile) later in PS.

> I shoot in RAW. sRGB is set on camera.

The sRGB setting in camera does not have impact here. It is used for the embedded jpg preview and for the actual image only if you shoot jpeg.

> The problem is that after I open my photo in Photoshop and enable
>   "Proof Colors" (set to "Monitor RGB") it looks pretty different that
>   it was in Adobe Camera Raw (ACR).

I think this is a sign that there is something wrong with the soft proof setting or the Monitor RGB profile is not actual measured profile of the monitor in its current setting.

> That means I can't do color correction in ACR.

The colors you get and see in ACR are probably more correct than those you see in the soft proof with Monitor RGB. I only use soft proof for print preparation, but if I wanted to figure out what is wrong with the Monitor RGB profile, at this point I would recalibrate my display, get one or more of the test images available on the internet to verify the soft proof is working correctly, shoot Xrite Color Checker and see if the representation in ACR or soft proof is correct. I would also try soft proof with sRGB, which should not change the colors compared to ACR almost at all.